# Question about the uniform distribution and random variable operation

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

If I have a random variable with uniform distribution ranging from 0 to 1, as follows: $ X \sim U\left ( 0 ;1 \right ) $

And if I subtract that random variable $ X $ from 1, will the resulting random variable have the same distribution that  $ X $, that is,  $ 1 - X \sim X $ ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will, by symmetry. One can also calculate.

Comment: @AndréNicolas what I should study more in order to solve this kind of problems? What should I wonder? I have another one asking if $ X $ and $ Y $ are iid $ Poi(1) $ then $ X -  Y = 0 $. But I don't know what I have to consider when dealing with random variable operations. Thanks!

Comment: The problems you are doing, an the ones done in lectures/book, will give you the required experience. The answer to the Poisson question is no. The random variable $X-Y$ can in fact take on all integer values, positive, negative, and $0$. For the two random variables represent the results obtained in two *different* experiments.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But if i plugged the parameter 1 into the the poisson probability function, wouldn't $ X $ and $ Y $ output the same result ? Like, each $ x $ and $ y $ wouldn't be the same once I've plugged 1 into $ \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta ^{x}}{x!} $ and eventually they would cancel each other?

Comment: They don't cancel. For example we can have $X-Y=2$ in infinitely many ways, $X=2$, $Y=0$, $X=3$, $Y=1$, and so on.